# how qemu-kvm create a VM thread internally?

Tags: linux, qemu, kvm

Now I am doing a project on qemu-kvm and linux task scheduler.I know each VCPU is a normal task created by qemu to the linux OS. Then I try to execute the qemu command to see how the task is created. I use strace to track all the system calls. There are no things like "fork" or "pthreadcreate".But I have seen this:

```
open("/dev/kvm", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)    = 3
ioctl(3, KVM_GET_API_VERSION, 0)        = 12
ioctl(3, KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION, 0x19)     = 0
ioctl(3, KVM_CREATE_VM, 0)              = 4
ioctl(3, KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION, 0x4)      = 1
ioctl(3, KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION, 0x4)      = 1
ioctl(4, KVM_SET_TSS_ADDR, 0xfffbd000)  = 0
ioctl(3, KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION, 0x25)     = 0
ioctl(3, KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION, 0xb)      = 1
ioctl(4, KVM_CREATE_PIT, 0xb)           = 0
ioctl(3, KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION, 0xf)      = 2
ioctl(3, KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION, 0x3)      = 1
ioctl(3, KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION, 0)        = 1
ioctl(4, KVM_CREATE_IRQCHIP, 0)         = 0
ioctl(3, KVM_CHECK_EXTENSION, 0x1a)     = 0
```

So it looks that it opens  the devices /dev/kvm and did some ioctl syscalls. I believe this is the place where the VM thread is actually created. Right? I am new to the OS stuff and I will appreciate if anyone can give me some clue:> Thanks

Comment: @duskwuff  But from what I learnt, in KVM ,each VCPU in a VM is a thread as seen by the host linux

Comment: Not exactly. Each VCPU is just an individual runnable object. See http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kvm/api.txt for details on the KVM ioctls.

Comment: @duskwuff  Hi.I have checked the document.It's really helpful.Thanks. I have seen there is a ioctl(KVM_RUN) call. I think maybe this is the call which will start the vcpu process. Then I have tracked the qemu and kvm source code. I have seen this call will call another function called kvm_arch_vcpu_ioctl_run which will be different based on different arch. But I still can not find the syscall like fork(). Generally I want to find when the qemu-kvm fork a thread for the new vcpu in the code:>

Comment: why are you expecting a fork() syscall? pthread_create() doesn't use fork().  Did you trace the clone() syscall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VCPU is neither a OS thread nor a process. To understand how VCPU works, first we should figure out how guest OS is running on `Intel VT-x` architecture.

`Intel VT-x` proposed a new mode methodology with two modes: `VMX root mode` and `VMX non-root mode`, for running host VMM and guest respectively. `Intel VT-x` also contains a new structure: `VMCS`, which saves all information both host and guest need. `VMCS` is one per guest.

KVM is a hardware-assisted hypervisor and leverages `Intel VT-x`. The host Linux KVM is running in `VMX root mode`. When KVM decides to switch CPU mode to run a guest, KVM dumps all current contexts to `VMCS` and executes a "VMLAUNCH" instruction. "VMLAUNCH" will transfer CPU from `VMX root mode` to `VMX non-root mode`, and load guest context from VMCS, then start or continue to execute guest code.

In summary, the guest code is running directly on CPU in `VMX non-root mode`. no software emulation layer for VCPU is needed. That's why KVM has better performance, and there is no specific thread for guest.

`/dev/kvm` is created by `kvm.ko`, which is only a KVM interface for QEMU. Your `strace` output showed how QEMU was interacting with KVM and controlling the underlying guests. You can never find a `fork` or `clone` system call in KVM.

For more KVM detail especially VCPU, you can read KVM code in `arch/x86/kvm/vmx.c` for more VCPU implementation detail based on `Intel VT-x`.

Answer (score 6):

Even though a VCPU is an OS object different from a thread or a process, and VCPU objects are created with the KVM_CREATE_VCPU ioctl, QEMU is indeed creating a thread per VCPU. The guest runs (the physical CPU enters VMX non-root mode) when QEMU does KVM_RUN from that thread.  KVM_CREATE_VCPU returns a new file descriptor, and that's the fd you'll see in the KVM_RUN ioctl.

VCPU threads might be missing from your strace because you did not use the `-ff` option. `-ff` asks strace to also trace other threads than the initial one.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about strace -ff option.                     #strace a process and follow all forks :
strace -ff -p12345